# Cómo hacer guardar y cargar partida en el ahorcado JAVA

Tags: java

un compañero y yo tenemos una duda. Estamos realizando una práctica de programación y hay varios apartados que suman puntos y uno de ellos es el **guardar** y **cargar** partida.

Le hemos dado mil vueltas, tenemos una ligera idea de cómo hacerlo pero estamos muy atascados y no conseguimos sacarlo. Hemos llegado a la conclusión de realizar un objeto que guarde los bytes y luego con el cargar lo mismo.

Conclusión, tenemos el juego del ahorcado en el cual hacemos que todos los caracteres de la frase se sustituyan por guiones y tu por consola vas introduciendo las letras y a medida de que vas acertando, la frase se va mostrando. Ej: "hola mundo" > ---- ----- > elijes la letra o > -o-- ----o

Necesitamos guardar el estado de la frase, las "vidas" que tiene y luego cargarla igual que la dejamos cuando guardamos. Si la guardamos así -o-- ---- que salga en el momento de cargar igual.

```
    public class Juego implements Serializable {

    private Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Main mainPrincipal = new Main();

    public String entradaTexto;
    public int puntosGeneral;
    public int puntosResta;

    //Rutas de los archivos de guardado y cargado.
    public String archivoGuardarPartida = mainPrincipal.cargaProperties("ruta_guardar");
    public String archivoEstadoActualPartida = mainPrincipal.cargaProperties("ruta_estadoactual");
    
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Juego() {
        entradaTexto = " ";
        //Le damos valor en este punto debido a que si no se acumulan los valores.
        puntosGeneral = Integer.parseInt(mainPrincipal.cargaProperties("puntuacion_general"));
        puntosResta = Integer.parseInt(mainPrincipal.cargaProperties("puntuacion_resta"));
    }

    public void juegoGeneral(String frase) {
        boolean continuar = true;
        System.out.println("\nMUCHA SUERTE JUGADOR. PARA GUARDAR LA PARTIDA ESCRIBE LA COMBINACION 666");

        while (true) {
            continuar = false;
            for (char caracterSecreto : frase.toCharArray()) {
                if (entradaTexto.indexOf(caracterSecreto) == -1) {
                    System.out.print("-");
                    continuar = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(caracterSecreto);
                }
            }
            if (puntosGeneral <= 0) {
                System.out.println("\n\t¡¡¡HAS PERDIDO!!!");
                break;
            }
            if (!continuar) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("\tPuntos: " + puntosGeneral);
            System.out.println("\nLetra-Consonante || Adivinar palabra: ");
            String resultado = teclado.next().toUpperCase();

            entradaTexto = entradaTexto + resultado;

            if (!frase.contains(resultado)) {
                puntosGeneral = puntosGeneral - puntosResta;
            }

            if (resultado.contains("666")) {
                System.out.println("**** Guardando ****");
                guardarPartida();
            }
        }
        puntuacion();
    }

    
    public void puntuacion() {
        if (puntosGeneral >= 850) {
            System.out.print("\n\t¡¡¡GANASTE!!!" + "\n\tPuntos: " + puntosGeneral + " || RANGO: S ");
            System.out.println();
        } else if (puntosGeneral >= 750 && puntosGeneral < 850) {
            System.out.print("\n\t¡¡¡GANASTE!!!" + "\n\tPuntos: " + puntosGeneral + " || RANGO: A ");
            System.out.println();
        } else if (puntosGeneral >= 500 && puntosGeneral < 750) {
            System.out.print("\n\t¡¡¡GANASTE!!!" + "\n\tPuntos: " + puntosGeneral + " || RANGO: B ");
            System.out.println();
        } else if (puntosGeneral >= 350 && puntosGeneral < 500) {
            System.out.print("\n\t¡¡¡GANASTE!!!" + "\n\tPuntos: " + puntosGeneral + " || RANGO: C ");
            System.out.println();
        } else if (puntosGeneral < 350) {
            System.out.print("\n\t¡¡¡GANASTE!!!" + "\n\tPuntos: " + puntosGeneral + " || RANGO: D ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Metodos de lectura de los archivos Facil , Normal y Dificil. || Metodo
     * cargar || Metodo de guardado *
     */
    public String leerArchivo(String archivo) {
        String resultado = "";
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        try {
            ArrayList<String> lecturaArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(archivo), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            if (!lecturaArrayList.isEmpty()) {
                resultado = lecturaArrayList.get(aleatorio.nextInt(lecturaArrayList.size()));
            } else {
                System.err.println("El archivo no tiene contenido. Escribe alguna frasuna en él tio!!!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error de lectura. No se encuentra el archivo.");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            //Se trata en el else del try leerArchivo()
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    public void cargarPartida(){
        try {
            Juego juego;
            ObjectInputStream lector = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivoGuardarPartida));
            //juego = (Juego) lector.readObject();
            ((Juego) lector.readObject() ).getEntradaTexto();
            ((Juego) lector.readObject() ).getPuntosGeneral();
            ((Juego) lector.readObject() ).getPuntosResta();
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No se encuentra fichero");
        } catch (InvalidClassException ice) {
            System.out.println("GAGAGAGAGA");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Los datos obtenidos no permiten recuperar la partida");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException");

        }
        
    }

    public void guardarPartida() {
        Juego a = new Juego();
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archivoGuardarPartida))) {
            oos.writeObject(a);
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }

    /**
     * Metodos GETTER. *
     */
    public String getEntradaTexto() {
        return entradaTexto;
    }

    public int getPuntosGeneral() {
        return puntosGeneral;
    }

    public int getPuntosResta() {
        return puntosResta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay varias opciones para ésto, se pueden complicar todo lo que quieran. Pueden tener una clase POJO que tenga como atributos las cosas que necesitas guardar (EstadoJuego, algo así, sean creativos!) y serializan y guardan en un archivo esa serialización. Luego pueden implementar cargarJuego, que lee el archivo y deserializa ese archivo en una instancia de esa clase EstadoJuego. De ahí en adelante, el mundo es suyo

Comment: si lo he entendido, todo lo que me has dicho ya lo tengo hecho con la diferencia de que en vez de una clase aparte, la tengo en la misma del juego y esa clase ya está serializada. Se supone que el método guardar funciona pero tampoco lo sabemos a ciencia cierta porque el método cargarPartida() no sabemos como hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

A la clase le falta el `serialVersionUID` y es sano que lo tenga. Revisen qué es y por qué se sugiere; el IDE debe ayudarles a generarlo sin mucho lío.

Sobre la deserialización, no necesitan mapear cosas atributo por atributo. Si todo se hizo bien, es posible convertir el bytestream de regreso a la instancia de la clase. Lo que les falta es tener atributos que guarden el estado de la frase, etc (y actualizar esas variables durante el juego).

```java
Juego object1 = null;
try
        {   
            // Reading the object from a file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);
              
            // Method for deserialization of object
            object1 = (Juego)in.readObject();
              
            in.close();
            file.close();
              
            System.out.println("Listooo!");
            
        }
          
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException!");
        }
          
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException!");
        }
```